# How to formulate a data fitting problem as a least squares problem

Tags: least-squares

Formulate the data fitting problem as a least squares problem

$\frac {1}{2} \Vert Ax-b \Vert_2^2 $

I thought I was supposed to wrote it like this:

$ \frac {1}{2} x^THx + g^T+ \gamma$ but actually that's an unconstrained
quadratic program; any help?

Comment: In the data fitting problem we minimize an error function which in vectorized is $||Ax-b||^2_{2}$. The second equation is the quadratic form of the last equation. I would like to help but I am not sure about what are you asking.

Comment: The complete question is this one: "What is A, b, x and n (you should write expressions for A, b, x and n)?"

Comment: Mistery solved. I missed the first exercise sheet  :D

Comment: Matrix $A$ usually is the data matrix, $x$ the linear combination of them and $b$ the target values. By the way good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer adding the entire text of the excercise that now makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

In data fitting, we are interested to solve:

$$\boldsymbol \theta = \underset{{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \in \mathbb{R} ^{M+1}}{\text{minimize}}J(\boldsymbol{\theta})$$

The error function $J\colon \mathbb{R^{M+1}}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $$J(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \frac{1}{2N} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \{h_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\phi}^{(n)})-t^{(n)}\}^2$$

where $\boldsymbol{\phi}:\mathbf{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{\mathcal{H}}$ a map/transformation function. The hypothesis $h_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\mathbf{\phi}^{(n)})$ we want to fit is given by:

$$h_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\phi}^{(n)}) = h(\boldsymbol{\phi}^{(n)},\boldsymbol{\theta}) =  \theta_0 + \theta_1 \phi^{(n)}_1 + \theta_2 \phi^{(n)}_2 + \dots + \theta_D \phi^{(n)}_D = \sum\limits_{d=0}^D \theta_d \phi^{(n)}_d, \quad \phi^{(n)}_0 = 1$$

If we define the parameters vector $\boldsymbol{\theta} = [\theta_0, \theta_2, \dots, \theta_D]^T \in \mathbb{R^{D+1}}$ the vectorized form of the hypothesis and the error functions respectively is $$h_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{\phi}^{(n)}) = \boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\phi}^{(n)}$$ and 
$$J(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \frac{1}{2N} (\boldsymbol{\Phi}\boldsymbol{\theta}- \mathbf{t})^T(\boldsymbol{\Phi}\boldsymbol{\theta}- \mathbf{t}) = \frac{1}{2N}||\boldsymbol{\Phi}\boldsymbol{\theta}- \mathbf{t}||^2$$ with

$$\boldsymbol{\Phi} = \begin{bmatrix}
      (\boldsymbol{\phi}^{(1)})^T \\[0.3em]
      (\boldsymbol{\phi}^{(2)})^T  \\[0.3em]
      \vdots \\[0.3em]
      (\boldsymbol{\phi}^{(n)})^T
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
      \phi^{(1)}_1 & \phi^{(1)}_2 & \dots & \phi^{(1)}_D \\[0.3em]
      \phi^{(2)}_1 & \phi^{(2)}_2 & \dots & \phi^{(2)}_D \\[0.3em]
      \vdots \\[0.3em]
      \phi^{(N)}_1 & \phi^{(N)}_2 & \dots & \phi^{(N)}_D \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}$$

Finally, the quadratic form of the error function is:

$$J(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \frac{1}{2N} \Bigg\{ \boldsymbol{\theta}^T \boldsymbol{\Phi}^T\boldsymbol{\Phi}\boldsymbol{\theta} -2 \boldsymbol{t}^T \boldsymbol{\Phi} \boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{t}^T\boldsymbol{t} \Bigg\}$$

<sup>PS: This methodology is also called multivariable linear regression.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Formulate the data fitting problem:

$\hat y(\theta)=\hat y(\theta,t)={\theta}_0+{\theta}_1e^{-t}+{\theta}_2t^2 $
$\theta=[{\theta}_0,{\theta}_1,{\theta}_2]$

$y_i=\hat y(\theta,t_i)+e_i$ $i=1,2,..,m$

as a least squares problem

$\frac {1}{2} \Vert Ax-b \Vert_2^2 $

I did this way:

A=$\begin{bmatrix}1& e^{-t}& t^2\\1& e^{-t}& t^2 \\ ..&..&..\\1& e^{-t}& t^2\end{bmatrix} $ $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times3}$

x=$\begin{bmatrix} {\theta}_0 \\ {\theta}_1 \\ {\theta}_2 \end{bmatrix} $

$b=y_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$

$n=3$

Is it right?